# Override og:description vía parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Lets say we have

```
<head>
..
..
<meta property="og:description" content="Default Description"/>  
..
</hea>
```

And then

```
<a onclick="var url=document.location.href; window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(url),'ventanacompartir', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=450');"
 href="javascript: void(0);" id="fbCompartir" title="" class="mx">
          <img alt="compartirFB" src="//d2p65vgzoeytng.cloudfront.net/nPromociones/producto/masNochesMasDescuento/img/icoPromoCompartirFacebook.gif">
</a>
```

As you can see i am sending to sharer.php vía u parameter the current url, how cand i send a custom text overriding the og:descripion? for example

```
<a onclick="var url=document.location.href; window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&d='+$('#description').text(),'ventanacompartir', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=450');"
 href="javascript: void(0);" id="fbCompartir" title="" class="mx">
          <img alt="compartirFB" src="//d2p65vgzoeytng.cloudfront.net/nPromociones/producto/masNochesMasDescuento/img/icoPromoCompartirFacebook.gif">
</a>
```

This is just fiction but is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. Not in javascript anyway - the facebook crawler doesnt read javascript. You will need to put the description you want directly into the url being shared. You could always change the og:description on the server in your php (or whatever server language you use) based on a parameter you send in. Make sure you enumerate them though so users can't write their own descriptions!

Comment: not entirely true; i know it does not read javascript but sharer.php reads parameters -it does not really matter if you generated in javascript-; like 'u' (url), so i thought why not 'd' (description)

Comment: ah I see what you mean. But no, you still can't do it I'm afraid! :(